# Is Dumbledore a Gryffindor?

Tags: harry-potter, albus-dumbledore

I was reading [Why Didn't Dumbledore Take the Sword of Gryffindor With Him to the Sea Cave (Locket Horcrux)?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/19164/why-didnt-dumbledore-take-the-sword-of-gryffindor-with-him-to-the-sea-cave-loc). According to [DVK's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/19165/1718), Dumbledore was a Gryffindor:

> If an emergency situation arose where a sword was needed, surely Dumbledore, as a worthy Gryffindor, had the option of pulling the sword out of a Hat.

Is there any canon reference for this other than the argument that Dumbledore was brave?

Comment: At first I read this question as "Is Dumbledore a Gryffon?"  I wish that were the actual question.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Yes, as [documented at the HP Lexicon](http://www.hp-lexicon.org/wizards/dumbledore.html#Hogwarts).

And…

The first time Harry and Ron meet Hermione, she says that she’s hoping to be sorted into Gryffindor, and that Dumbledore was a previous member:

> I’ve been asking around and I hope I’m in Gryffindor, it sounds by far the best, I hear Dumbledore himself was one.
>
> — *Philosopher’s Stone*, chapter 6 (*Platform Nine and Three-Quarters*)

Also…

In the *Goblet of Fire* film, Dumbledore tells Harry:

> I never liked these curtains. I set them on fire in my fourth year. Accidentally, of course.

I doubt Dumbledore would care enough about curtains in a room in someone else's house to set fire to them and remember it to make the comment.

Comment: I liked the curtain quote. Is it there in the book or only the movie? A quick google search gave me plenty of references to the movie

Comment: @jogabonito It's in the book, though I couldn't tell you exactly when.

Comment: Also, the door knocker on his oak doors was the head of a griffin.

Comment: @jogabonito: Fairly sure it was an addition on the part of the screenwriters; I’ve scoured the text of *GoF* and can’t find any mention of it.

Answer (score 28):

In Harry Potter and the Philosopher's/Sorcerer's Stone Hermione mentions

> Do either of you know what house you'll be in? I've been asking around, and I hope I'm in 
>   Gryffindor, it sounds by far the best; I hear Dumbledore himself was in it

It is also revealed on Pottermore in the Gryffindor welcome letter that Dumbledore is a Gryffindor.  [(Link)](http://pottermorespoilers.tumblr.com/post/8984341241/welcome-to-gryffindor) for those that don't have access to Pottermore.

Comment: Nice, with the Pottermore link!