# Why Dumbledore didn't tell Harry how to destroy horcruxes?

Tags: harry-potter, horcrux, albus-dumbledore

Knowing that it is difficult to destroy a horcrux, why didn't Dumbledore just tell Harry (during his meetings in Harry Potter and the Half Blood Prince) that he had to use the Sword of Gryffindor to destroy them. Why did he want him to figure out this on his own?

Comment: Was Dumbledore aware of this fact in the first place?

Comment: @Rebel-Scum, yes, he used the Sword to destroy one of the Horcruxes himself.

Comment: He probably intended to tell Harry or to show him once they retrieved that Horrcrux from the Cave. But, you know... Draco managed to surprise Dumbledore by successfully repairing the vanishing cabinet and taking Hogwarts. Then, a serie of events unfolded finishing with the death of Dumbledore, leaving his lessons with Harry unconcluded.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why didn't Dumbledore leave Harry a big pile of basilisk fangs?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/126319/why-didnt-dumbledore-leave-harry-a-big-pile-of-basilisk-fangs)